# Time difference in 24 hour format

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two times in 24 hour format :

```
| JamProduksi| JamKerja |
|------------|----------|
| 22:00:00   |05:00:00  |
```

i want the result is  07:00:00

i'm using timediff in mysql, but when JamProduksi is Higher than JamKerja , it gives me a result --> -17:00:00

can you help me guys?

Comment: What happens when you test 24:00:00 and 07:00:00?

Comment: How do you know it's 7 hours?

Comment: because in 24 hour format 22:00:00 = 10 P.M & 05:00:00 = 5 A.M. So the difference is 7 hours

Comment: @SandhiZukhrufZusiarta that is not necessarily correct at all.  When no *date* is provided, the difference between two times depends on the order and the definition of its interpretation, and typically has at least two likely values: 05:00:00 is both 17 hours *before* 22:00:00 (earlier the same day in this case) and also 7 hours *after* 22:00:00 (across midnight in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no one is working longer than 24 hours you could modulate the results to fit within one day.

```
CREATE TABLE `production_working_times` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `JamProduksi` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `JamKerja` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `production_working_times` (`id`, `JamProduksi`, `JamKerja`)
VALUES
    (1, '22:00:00', '05:00:00'),
    (2, '05:00:00', '22:00:00');

SELECT 
    JamProduksi started_work,
    JamKerja finished_work, 
    -- convert back to time
    sec_to_time(
    -- remove any time beyond 24 hours
    mod(
        -- convert the time seconds and add the number of seconds in one day
        time_to_sec(
            -- get the time difference
            timediff(JamKerja,JamProduksi)
        ) + 86400
    ,86400
    )
) hours_worked
FROM production_working_times

-- sample results
started_work    finished_work   hours_worked
22:00:00    05:00:00    07:00:00
05:00:00    22:00:00    17:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Store the date as well and use `TIMEDIFF()`;
- If you know that one value must be bigger than the other, you can use `SUBTIME()`.

Comment: can you give me another idea, because your answer is not working for me. it give me same result . i want the result is 07:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` to check which one is greater:

```
select
(
    case 
       when JamProduksi > JamKerja
       then TIMEDIFF('24:0:0',TIMEDIFF(JamProduksi, JamKerja))   

      when JamProduksi < JamKerja
       then TIMEDIFF('24:0:0',TIMEDIFF(JamKerja, JamProduksi))
 end
)
```

Comment: That would return `17:00:00`. Also both your cases have the same condition.

Comment: can youy give me any idea, beacuse your query doesn't working on me

Comment: you can check this, i have made for you http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d55ea/1